# Finding nearest number between two lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list of dataframes (df1) and another list of dataframes (df2) which hold values required to find the 'nearest value' in the first list.

```
df1<-list(d1=data.frame(y=1:10), d2=data.frame(y=3:20))
df2<-list(d3=data.frame(y=2),d4=data.frame(y=4))
```

Say I have this function:

```
df1[[1]]$y[which(abs(df1[[1]]$y-df2[[1]])== min(abs(df1[[1]]$y-df2[[1]])))]
```

This function works perfectly in finding the closest value of df2 value 1 in df1. What I can't achieve is getting to work with lapply as in something like:

```
lapply(df1, function(x){
  f<-x$y[which(abs(x$y-df2) == min(abs(x$y - df2)))]
})
```

I would like to return a dataframe with all f values which show the nearest number for each item in df1.

Thanks,
M

Comment: Which data.frame in df2 are you trying to compare the values in df1 to in your `lapply`?

Comment: So they are numbered above as 2 and 4, so it would be df2$d3$y. So, d3 could be comparing to d1 and d4 would be comparing to d2

Comment: So for d1 in df1, we want to compare y to 2 and 4, and for d2 in df1 we want to compare y to 2 and 4?

Comment: Not quite, I want to compare the single value (#2) in df2$d3 to the numbers in df1$d1. Then compare df2$d4 value to the numbers in df1$d2 in a loop.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using data.frames instead of vectors?

Comment: Yes as my lists are lists of dataframes which require subsetting via the 'looking up' of values derived from each data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to compare the first `data.frames` in df1 and df2 to each other, and the second `data.frames` in df1 and df2 to each other. It would also be useful to use the `which.min` function (check out `help(which.min))`.

**edit**

In response to your comment, you could use `mapply` instead:

```
> mapply(function(x,z) x$y[which.min(abs(x$y - z$y))], df1, df2)
d1 d2 
 2  4
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the answer I'm looking for, it works don't get me wrong, but I would still have to loop over my data frames to bind each column from df2 to df1 at the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's real problem is unclear, but I would probably do...

```
library(data.table)
DT1 = rbindlist(unname(df1), idcol=TRUE)
DT2 = rbindlist(unname(df2), idcol=TRUE)

DT1[DT2, on=c(".id","y"), roll="nearest"]

#    .id y
# 1:   1 2
# 2:   2 4
```